# Postgres search much slower using combined index for just the first item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

I have two indexes showing very different results for similar searches, and I don't know why this is:

```
# The two indexes
"index_buyer_suppliers_on_buyer_id" btree (buyer_id)
"index_buyer_suppliers_on_supplier_id_and_buyer_id" UNIQUE, btree (supplier_id, buyer_id)

# The two searches
@current_suppliers = BuyerSupplier.where("buyer_id = ?", @entity.id).length
@current_buyers    = BuyerSupplier.where("supplier_id = ?", @entity.id).length

# The EXPLAINs
1. EXPLAIN SELECT "buyer_suppliers".* FROM "buyer_suppliers" WHERE (buyer_id = 891285);
                                             QUERY PLAN                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using index_buyer_suppliers_on_buyer_id on buyer_suppliers  (cost=0.43..54.48 rows=15 width=56)
   Index Cond: (buyer_id = 891285)
(2 rows)


2. EXPLAIN SELECT "buyer_suppliers".* FROM "buyer_suppliers" WHERE (supplier_id = 891285);
                                             QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on buyer_suppliers  (cost=2309.31..32194.90 rows=99727 width=56)
   Recheck Cond: (supplier_id = 891285)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_buyer_suppliers_on_supplier_id_and_buyer_id  (cost=0.00..2284.38 rows=99727 width=0)
         Index Cond: (supplier_id = 891285)
(4 rows)

# The EXPLAINs with (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
1. EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT "buyer_suppliers".* FROM "buyer_suppliers" WHERE (buyer_id = 891285);
                                              QUERY PLAN                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using index_buyer_suppliers_on_buyer_id on buyer_suppliers  (cost=0.43..54.48 rows=15 width=56) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (buyer_id = 891285)
   Buffers: shared hit=3
 Planning Time: 0.103 ms
 Execution Time: 0.057 ms
(5 rows)

Time: 0.399 ms

2. EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT "buyer_suppliers".* FROM "buyer_suppliers" WHERE (supplier_id = 891285);
                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on buyer_suppliers  (cost=2309.31..32194.90 rows=99727 width=56) (actual time=8.584..32.907 rows=99205 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (supplier_id = 891285)
   Heap Blocks: exact=9016
   Buffers: shared hit=9399
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_buyer_suppliers_on_supplier_id_and_buyer_id  (cost=0.00..2284.38 rows=99727 width=0) (actual time=7.316..7.317 rows=99205 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (supplier_id = 891285)
         Buffers: shared hit=383
 Planning Time: 0.107 ms
 Execution Time: 39.306 ms
(9 rows)

Time: 39.806 ms
```

I always thought that just using the first part of a combined index was completely fine, but here we see a massive performance degradation from doing so. Why is this happening? Does this mean the recommended indexes to have would be these four: 1) `:buyer_id`, 2) `:supplier_id`, 3) `[:buyer_id, :supplier_id]`, 4) `[:supplier_id, :buyer_id]`? This seems like overkill but based on the above is it perhaps necessary?

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` please, ideally after setting `track_io_timing = on`.

Comment: Finding and returning 15 rows can understandably be faster than for 99727 rows..

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Just added the new info.

Comment: @JGH that makes sense of course. Do you think there should be no detrimental effects otherwise of a single-column vs. dual-column index when searching for just the one attribute?

Comment: The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) says for an index on (x,y): _"For queries involving only x, the multicolumn index could be used, though it would be larger and hence slower than an index on x alone."_ But honestly I wouldn't consider a query completing in 39 milliseconds to be inefficient.

Comment: See this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hardly surprising that an index scan that returns 99205 takes somewhat more time than an index scan that returns no row at all. 40 milliseconds doesn't seem slow for that. So there is no evidence here that using a multi-column index is much slower than a single column index.

To verify that, you can create an index on only `supplier_id` and see if it is much slower. Any speed gains would have to be in the first 7 milliseconds when the actual index is scanned. The smaller index will be slightly faster, and PostgreSQL will prefer it, but don't expect an average speed gain of more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: @engineersmnky True. I have added some more (hopefully useful) information.